# How do I report a bug to Microsoft?

Tags: excel

I found a Bug in Microsoft Excel that has obviously been in there for many years. I use Excel via API and therefore this component needs to be fixed.

The following discussion:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-do-you-report-a-product-bug-to-microsoft/0ef12a13-78eb-40c1-b946-f963cbe26b6e

just yields:
https://feedback.office.microsoft.com/default.aspx?productkey=office2007

but that seems to be outdated.

**How do I report a bug to Microsoft?**

Comment: Off topic? Using an API is only possible if it works. Fixing it is a major step of software development. In Open source projects you can fix things you self. For Microsoft fixing bugs they do not know of is impossible and since telling Microsoft bugs is also a mission impossible: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/mission_impossible_submitting.html such bugs are never fixed.

Comment: recently I found 5 bugs in powerpoints API the worst one was that you can't even save a presentation via API on Powerpoint 2011 on MacOS. Same story - no way to report the bug to Microsoft. Same issue with Stackoverflow - for an other API the discussion would be open - why not for Microsoft?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft does not accept bug reports on Excel.

You need to contact their support and [send your case](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wf=0&wfName=productselection&gprid=918&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn&ccsid=635695094634585701)

Comment: Where is the one for Word???