# Can't edit cell Values after clicking Excel button

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I have a macro that removes a line from a named range. 
After pressing the button to run that macro, I can't edit cells anymore.
Not in that range, nor in any editable cells in my protected worksheet.
 
Seems that workbook with the same code didn't work in Excel 2010 too. 
This is my macro :

```
Sub DeleteParameterRow(ByVal tCell As Range)

    '''this procedure delete a row from one of the parameters lists
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim iRowToDelete As Integer

    Call Unprotect_All()

    If IsPartOfRange(tCell, NamedRange("Param_ParametersList"), False) Then

        tCell.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Else

        MsgBox("Please select one of the parameters list", vbInformation, "Error")

    End If

EndProc:
    Call Protect_All()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number)
    GoTo EndProc

End Sub


Function IsPartOfRange(ByVal rSearchRange As Range, ByVal rSearchInRange As Range, ByVal bIsEntireRange As Boolean) As Boolean
    '''this function gets a small range, a big range and if it is supposed to be the entire range, and check
    '''if the smaller range is part of the bigger one, and if it is  the entire range
    IsPartOfRange = False

    If Not Intersect(rSearchRange, rSearchInRange) Is Nothing Then

        If bIsEntireRange = True Then

            If rSearchRange.Address = rSearchInRange.MergeArea.Address Then IsPartOfRange = True

        Else

            IsPartOfRange = True

        End If

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please provide some code for us to look at and see if we can reproduce. What version of Excel are you running on now? And what is your actual question?

Comment: are you disabling events at the start of the macro and then not re-enabling them at the end?  it'd be helpful to get more context (and code) to help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Is screenupdating turned back on?

Comment: Looks like screenupdating issue to me as well. Add `Application.Screeupdating=True` at the end of the code and check again. Has happened to me as well even though I did not set it to false in the begining

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Rout your comment gives hope, since I didn't turn screenupdating to false. I will try later

Comment: @Rik Sportel, @Siddharth Rout Well, I just tasted the code with `screenupdating` turned back on, and unfortunately this those not help. I saw in SO a post with workaround, to switch to another workbook or even worksheet than go back to WS in question. But again, when doing so programmatically it seems to not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

See my last comment were I mentioned it seems to be a kind of "Refresh" problem.
 After code runs something is stacked in Excel that prevents edits. ( [No way to report bugs to MS... :(](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30747488/2398630)
)
To force a "Refresh" programmatically I found clearing the content of an arbitrarily cell is usefull. 
 So Adding the line `tCell.ClearContents` befor `EndProc:` did the trik.

Comment: I reopen the answer since I discovered in another workbook that it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem was bothering me from some time with no definitive answer around. You can select another sheet then back to your sheet and edit works again, or this trick with cell ClearContents.

I think the answer, at least in my case, is having on sheet, an ActiveX command buttons (and eventually other controls) that take the focus by default when clicked. Setting this feature to False in the button properties solve the edit problems easily, though for a combobox, that's causing the same issue, there is no take focus property!

The issue has nothing to do with the macro associated to the button as long as clicking the button with no macro to execute leads to blocking the edit, because of taking the focus in a particular way.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not working on that project anymore, but next time with Excel I will check, Thanks