# Range.R1C1 Incrementing by 2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to fill down some formulas, tried using the `.FillDown` but it's quite slow compared to using the below function.

However, the issue is that my formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H11,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")` is incrementing by 2 on `$H11`

```
Private Sub AutoFillFormulas()

    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    Range("R11:AH" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = Range("R1:AH1").FormulaR1C1
    
End Sub
```

Expected Results:

R11 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H11,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")`

R12 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H12,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")`

R13 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H13,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")`

Actual Results:

R11 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H11,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")`

R12 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H13,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")`

R13 = `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H15,AdHoc!A:K,11,FALSE),"---")`

Comment: `but it's quite slow compared` - disable automatic calculations before doing that?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, it does not happen when using `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`.

Comment: @GSerg: if it really is a bug, how will we explain Microsoft they need to solve it?

Comment: @Dominique With [difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30747440/11683).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if you copy a formula eg `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[10]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")` with `FormulaR1C1` it will increase the row number `R[10]C8` to `R[11]C8` and so on. Resulting in the below:

```
R1C1                                                                  A1
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[10]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H21,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[11]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H23,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[12]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H25,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[13]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H27,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[14]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H29,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[15]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H31,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[16]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H33,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[17]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H35,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[18]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H37,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[19]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H39,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[20]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H41,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[21]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H43,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R[22]C8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")            =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H45,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
```

While if you copy down using `.Formula` it will use this formula `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H11,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")` and increase the `$H11` to `$H12` and so on resulting in:

```
R1C1                                                                  A1
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H11,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H12,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H13,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H14,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H15,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H16,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H17,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H18,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H19,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H20,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H21,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H22,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC8,AdHoc!C[-1]:C[9],11,FALSE),"---")                =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H23,AdHoc!Q:AA,11,FALSE),"---")
```

Not sure if this is a bug rather than a feature and just how R1C1 notation works.

---

Further it looks like it has to do with copying a range of multiple columns `Range("R11:AH" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = Range("R1:AH1").FormulaR1C1`

If you change to only one column `Range("R11:R" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = Range("R1:R1").FormulaR1C1` it does what the OP expected.

Comment: The conclusion that it may not be a bug appears to contradict the observation that it does not happen when copying within one column.

Comment: @GSerg Not necessarily, I think, because `= Range("R1:AH1").FormulaR1C1` is an array of formulas while `Range("R1:R1").FormulaR1C1` is a value (not an array), so it might handle it differently?

Comment: Yes, it might, but it shouldn't. And it doesn't with `.Formula`.